# Android set margin of view programmatically

Tags: java, android, view, margin

I wanted to set margin to View programmatically. Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llAttendeeList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#000000">

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/attendeelistview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:listSelector="#F6CECE" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the method when my button onClick to call out the popup Window view:

```
private void openPopUp() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                    context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_attendee_pop,
            null);
    llAttendeeList = (LinearLayout) popupView
            .findViewById(R.id.llAttendeeList);
    attendeeListView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.attendeelistview);


    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
    popupView.setLayoutParams(params);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 350);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
    attendeeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I tried to set margin to the popupView but no luck. The margin is not there. I wonder which part override it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manually set width and height of PopupWindow :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

popupWindow.setWidth(width-10);
popupWindow.setHeight(height-10);
```

Comment: @Denise,Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

try to use layout it will work

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams
(

    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,          
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  
);  

params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);  
 yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

follow this tutorial http://www.codota.com/android/classes/android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

Comment: I did used it. You can check the question I posted.

Comment: try to add LinearLayout.LayoutParams because it depends on which layout you are using brother..

Comment: Nope, doesnt work. It still took out the whole width of screen

Comment: follow that link it will give idea

Comment: @Denise give `static` width while creating *PopUpWindow* instead of `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: @kaushik Sorry but what do you mean by static width?

Comment: @Denise `final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            350, 350);` like this